# How to control the order of child project Gradle tasks from root build?

Tags: gradle, build, task

I have a Gradle project with two subprojects:

- `backend`
- `frontend`

I want to create a task in the parent project called `stage` which executes `:backend:build` but only after running `:frontend:clean` and `:backend:clean`.

I tried this but the `mustRunAfter` is ignored and the cleaning happens at the end of the build instead. What is wrong with it?

```
task stage(dependsOn: [':frontend:clean', ':backend:clean', ':backend:build'])
task(":backend:build").mustRunAfter(":frontend:clean", ":backend:clean")
```

I also tried replacing the second line with:

```
project("backend").build.mustRunAfter(":frontend:clean, ":backend:clean")
```

but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why non of my tries work but here is a working approach:

```
task stage(dependsOn: [':frontend:clean', ':backend:clean', ':backend:build'])
tasks.getByPath(":backend:build").mustRunAfter(":frontend:clean", ":backend:clean")
```